# react-native-navigation: how to hide bottomTabs when keyboard is shown?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am using the bottomTabs navigator from react-native-navigaton to navigation within my app. However, each time I have for example a `TextInput` field, the bottomTabs are being pushed up.

What is a possible way to hide the bottomTabs whenever the keyboard is being shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your android manifest in android/app/src/AndroidManifest.xml

in your activity tag add/replace this attribute

the bottom tab should be hidden now.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan"
```

Comment: funny, it also worked with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Comment: Do not forget do this after changes **cd android && ./gradlew clean**

Answer (score 8):

just add `tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true` to `screenOptions`

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically hide the bottom tab when the keyboard is open using React hooks

```js
  const _keyboardDidShow = useCallback(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      tabBarVisible: false,
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const _keyboardDidHide = useCallback(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      tabBarVisible: true,
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', _keyboardDidShow);
    Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', _keyboardDidHide);

    // cleanup function
    return () => {
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidShow', _keyboardDidShow);
      Keyboard.removeListener('keyboardDidHide', _keyboardDidHide);
    };
  }, [_keyboardDidHide, _keyboardDidShow]);
```

Comment: I think you are referring to `react-navigation` and not `react-native-navigation`

Answer (score 1):

### Answer for React Navigation V6 with or without a Custom tabBar

I'm using react navigation V6 since i'm using a custom tabBar the `tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true` prop not working but when i change the custom tabBar to default tab bar that prop works but i don't like the behavior  of that prop on android, so i used keyboard from react-native to check if the keyboard is active or not and setting the css display prop to 'none'

```js
  import { Keyboard, View } from "react-native";

  const [keyboardStatus, setKeyboardStatus] = useState<boolean>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const showSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
      setKeyboardStatus(true);
    });
    const hideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
      setKeyboardStatus(false);
    });

    return () => {
      showSubscription.remove();
      hideSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

so on the custom tab bar component now we can do like this.

```js
    <View style={
      [
        styles.mainContainer,
        keyboardStatus ? styles.hideTabNavigation : null,
      ]
    }
    >
    // your code here
   </View>
```

Hope this will help someone until they fix this issue!

Comment: Thanks, this is a better solution for my codebase

Comment: This works but there's a noticeable flicker when the tabBar disappears. I wonder if there's a way to make the tabBar to not change position at all and just stay behind the keyboard.